# Magento 2 data migration - MySQL versions (source/destination)

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7, magento2.3, data-migration-tool, magento2.3.5

I have always migrated from a Magento 1 server database copy that is local and restored on MySQL 5.7 (on the same database host as my Magento 2 migrate database).

I would usually use `<direct_document_copy>1</direct_document_copy>` in **config.xml**, but now I want to do a migration test from a live Magento 1 website - so I need to do this:
0

My question though : this live Magento 1 database is running on MySQL 5.6x, and I am aware that Magento 2.2+ runs on MySQL 5.7.  I need to test `migrate:delta` (delta migration) eventually, the databases I always ran tests on was offline *(so no database triggers will have any effect)*.

How would I do this migration when my source database version and destination database versions aren't the same?

Can I just run the migration on the live site?  I can't upgrade to MySQL 5.7 on the production server - because of the Magento 1 database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, it will work ok
connect to remote database, migrate all settings and data.
do some design changes, then migrate delta.

do not run `reset` on any operation `:settings` `:data` `:delta`
it will only add some artifacts.

Comment: Ok thank you for confirming, while waiting I have already attempted to do migration in the meantime.  Will give feedback if I see versions have issues.

(I run --reset on :data, works until _before_ any attributes get imported)

Comment: I have managed to run `migrate:data config.xml` and the import from remote database took around 7 hours.  I have issues with configurable products showing out of stock (created a question for this).    I will update this as soon as I manage to successfully do **delta migration** when running `migrate:delta` which I can't do yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a copy of magento 1 data base into your local server and then migrate it.

Comment: I mentioned that I used to do that before.  If I just 'copy database' then the **delta migration** what I am specifically inquiring about will not work (Triggers), so I can't ever do delta migration when I am ready.

Comment: If you are remigrating again using delta migration, then try to reset the database and migrate again

Comment: This is not possible, if the data migration tool worked better maybe, it does not work out of the box, and lots of things need to be fixed manually.

The initial data migration, then Magento 2 modules install, then configuring / testing everything, then installing the Theme (and applying theme customizations) spans days/weeks when I reset everything.   So I _need to be able to do_ **delta migration** as the final step.  

I am trying to say by the time things are ready, the **live website** will have new orders/customers/etc.